# Rails 5 has many through associations - Could not find table 'team_users'

Tags: associations, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-5

When I generate join table migration in Rails 5, an error occurs

Migration

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableTeamUser team user
```

20161011185253_create_join_table_team_user.rb

```
class CreateJoinTableTeamUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :teams, :users do |t|
      t.index [:team_id, :user_id]
      t.index [:user_id, :team_id]

      t.timestamps null: false, include_deleted_at: true
      t.userstamps index: true, include_deleter_id: true
    end
  end
end
```

team.rb

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_user
  has_many :users, through: :team_user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_user
  has_many :teams, through: :team_user
end
```

team_user.rb

```
class TeamUser < ApplicationRecord
  include Userstampable::Stampable

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team

  # validates :user_id, presence: true
  # validates :team_id, presence: true
end
```

Terminal - error

```
2.3.1 :001 > team = Team.first
...
2.3.1 :002 > me = User.first
...
2.3.1 :003 > team.users << me
...
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'team_users'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a table, so its better to use 'model' generator instead of migration, because ideally migration should be used to update existing table schema.

Try following:

```
rails g model team_user user:references team:references
```

then

```
rails db:migrate
```

Hope it helps you.